# Workflow database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm doing an app that will have a workflow with max 4 approvers.
They will aprove in steps. 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
There will be various workflows and approvers are different.
The DB is MySQL.
This is the best way to do this? I'm doing right?

```
ID | approver1 | flow1 | approver2 | flow2 | approver3 | flow3 | approver4 | flow4
```

Where `approverX`will be the `ID` of the user that approves and the `flowX` will be boolean `0` or `1`

This is the best way?

Comment: i think not because you violate the 1FN, there're repetition of information.

http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No!

What if 5 approvers are needed in the future? Change the DB design? How about

```
approve table
---------------
flow_id
aprover_id
step
result (bit)
```

Example table content

```
flow_id | aprover_id | step | result
1       | 1          | 1    | 1
1       | 4          | 2    | 1
1       | 4          | 3    | 0
1       | 1          | 4    | 0
2       | 7          | 1    | 1
2       | 7          | 2    | 0
2       | 7          | 3    | 1
```

Comment: Every time that step change the aprover will change?

Comment: You add a new record for every step

Comment: I've edited my question. There are many workflows and the approvers will change

Comment: Yes, that design will work with that requirements. I added a `result` column.

Comment: What is the purpose of result column

Comment: @juergend can you please explain the example table content and usage?